# Excel Dna Read UDF parameters from Excel ribbon

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I am very new to Excel dna.

I created a function, HotelDetail, the function takes 3 parameters, HotelId, Months(range of cells) and prices:

[image: HotelDetail example]

My aim is to create a ribbon button, UpdatePrices, on clicking this button its reads the parameters inserted in HotelDetail function to update DB. I manage to create the function and Ribbon but I can't find how to read the parameters on button clicked

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, and my approach was :

- Make your UDF Function to call a database proxy where you store the value to be updated
- When your user click on the *Update Prices* button, read all data which have been stored into the proxy and send them to the database.
- Ultimately, flush the proxy temp values.

On the other way, if you want to read from a DB without querying the database anytime a formula is entered / Excel refreshes values, use the same proxy for storing ids which need to be queried when the user presses a *Read Prices* button.

Hope this helps.